# Should numbers from user input be quoted in MySQL queries to help avoid SQL injection attacks?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, quotes

Should numbers from user input be quoted in MySQL queries to help avoid SQL injection attacks?

Say i have a form on a page asking for someone's age. They enter their age and hit submit. The following php code deals with the form submission: (age is an int field in the db table.)

```
$Number = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST["age"]);
$Query = "INSERT INTO details (age) VALUES ($Number)";
$Result = mysqli_query($dbc, $Query);
```

Instead of this, is there anything to be gained to enclosing the user input in single quotes, even though it is not a string? Like this:

```
...
$Query = "INSERT INTO details (age) VALUES ('$Number')";  <-- quotes
...
```

What about performing a `SELECT`? Is this:

```
$ID = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST["id"]);
$Query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$ID'";
$Result = mysqli_query($dbc, $Query);
```

better than:

```
$ID = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST["id"]);
$Query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $ID";      <-- no quotes
$Result = mysqli_query($dbc, $Query);
```

---

*NOTE: I am aware of prepared statements and usually use them over string concatenation but this is legacy code i'm dealing with. I want to secure it as best as i can.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add numbers, use the `intval`/`floatval` functions, don't use `mysql_real_escape_string` for those.

For everything you use `mysql_real_escape_string` for, you *must* use quotes, example:

```
$input = "foo'bar";
$input = mysql_real_escape_string($input);
//foo\'bar
mysql_query("SELECT $input");
//SELECT foo\'bar
//which is still an SQL syntax error.
```

Comment: +1 for the intval reference: when you expect an integer posted, verify that it is actually an integer by converting it with intval.

Comment: So would you put quotes around the int in the SQL string?

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear: numbers should be cast to numbers (intval/floatval), and _not_ use quotes, and mysql_real_escape_string does NOT come into play. However, if you don't do that and just blatently use `mysql_real_escape_string` on everything (some frameworks /libs even do this), you _must_ use quotes around those strings (mind you, strings, not numbers). I can't think of a way this would otherwise cause useful SQL-injection, but it can still lead to invalid queries.

Comment: Im confused, if you used 'mysql_real_escape_string' on an input you were expecting to be a number, would you still enclose that in quotes? Because at the minute we have an input class for sanitisation which as you said does actually apply mres to everything.

Comment: Yes, you should, because it doesn't make it a number, and `mysql_real_escape_string` expects to escape _strings_, which should _always_ be in quotes. If you want a field/type-agnostic input class which doesn't know or care it takes care of a number or not (and there are valid reasons to do that), use `mysql_real_escape_string` on everything, and everything should be in quotes. If you however _do_ know something should be a number, cast to it with `intval` or `floatval` as appopriate, and do not use quotes.

Answer (score 1):

You really shoud use sprintf, even if in legacy code it takes 2 mins to modify and is in my opinion totally worth the time.

Shamelessly ripped from php.net:

```
// Formulate Query
// This is the best way to perform an SQL query
// For more examples, see mysql_real_escape_string()
$query = sprintf("SELECT firstname, lastname, address, age FROM friends 
                 WHERE  firstname='%s' AND lastname='%s'",
                 mysql_real_escape_string($firstname),
                 mysql_real_escape_string($lastname));

// Perform Query
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Your query is now pretty much safe from being passed the wrong types to it's fields and unescaped caracters.

Comment: **Why** is sprintf any better?

Comment: Advantages could be better readability (depends), and it's the first step on the way to actual prepared statements (i.e. if you do change to it is is a lot easier to rewrite).

Comment: @user569090  Because it filters the values passed to your query for you. Your field is int? It will always receive int. Your field is a string? Sprintf will pass that argument _as a string_ for you. There are also many formatting options available for money formats, 0 padding and more, though I rarely use these they can be handy sometimes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was misled because your example does not include any numbers/integers and hence does not adress the original question about numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You SHOULD use the PHP filters, and filter for numbers - even for ranges, regular expressions; with default values, NULL on failure, etc.

http://hu.php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php

if the values come from a request variable, e.g. $_POST, see:

http://hu.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php